# difference between iftop vs tcpdump

Tags: linux

what is the difference between the two commands I know that almost both of them are tracing packets but not sure what scenario would you use which command, may you also provide some examples and visuals if that is possible?

Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 0):

Tcpdump will display each packet in the order they are exchanged. It is a convenient tool to debug a network protocol issue.

Iftop is more a monitoring tool. I won’t display each packet, but classify them according to the source/destination and displays metrics about them. It can be handy to know how much exchange there are and because of which connection.